# PHP Phar Deployment Performance

Tags: php, phar

I am considering architecting our php app's deployment process such that the build's output produces a single phar archive for the necessary code to run the app in production.  I am wondering about the performance of deploying a web app in this way versus the traditional model of checking out or copying the source tree itself to the document root for the web-server.

There are benefits to the packaged approach in that the package can be fully prepped by the CI server (removing test code for example) and then a single archive just copied to the server for deployment.  The pristine archives can be stored in a repository as well.

I don't want to use this approach if running the app as a phar will cause a bottleneck however. Are there issues with loading the source out of the phar?  The app uses autoloading via composer to load source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I [benchmarked a application](http://cweiske.de/tagebuch/php-phar-files.htm#benchmark) back in 2011; speed was not an issue with phar.

There will be minor problems loading source code and template files - depending on how you do it currently. But all in all, this won't be impossible problems.

Comment: Your benchmarks show that static files should not be in the phar. Would you be suggesting that when we package our PHP apps, we should package only the src code as phars, and all static files will be left outside?

Comment: I think you can cache static files both on server and on client side, and you can have a phar cache as well... I don't think speed will be an issue by static files either, but I'll check the stats...

Comment: @cweiske Have you tried it with http://www.php.net/manual/en/phar.configuration.php#ini.phar.cache-list ? And with or without digital signature verification?